# Extend rootfs partition at runtime

Tags: linux, yocto, partitioning, rootfs

I have an embedded Linux board with 16Go eMMC flash.

When I boot the image and I run `fdisk -l` I get this:

```
root@menzu:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk2: 14.62 GiB, 15678308352 bytes, 30621696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe00e5569

Device         Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk2p1 *     16384  186775  170392 83.2M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk2p2      196608 9177991 8981384  4.3G 83 Linux
```

As you can see, my eMMC /dev/mmcblk2 has 14.62 Gb size.

But, my Linux rootfs partiton has only 4.3G,

How can I extend its size at runtime to be 10Gb or 12Gb for example?

I tried `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk2p2` but it changed the blocks size to 1K and after that it only shows:

```
root@menzu:~# resize2fs /dev/mmcblk2p2
resize2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
The filesystem is already 1122673 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I can force the Yocto build to be 12Go, but that's not a good solution cuz the image will be large.

Comment: I'm suggesting redesign your system to use more partitions. The root needs to be generated as an image, but all others you can do is the install script. In the install script, you can create partitions on your eMMC and copy your file. I've got such a solution in my products and it works very well. I don't see an easy and safe way to resize it at runtime. How do you install image on eMMC now?

Comment: I'm working with an NXP product (IMX8MM) and using UUU (Universal Update Utility) of NXP to flash the eMMC, so, can you suggest to create new partition for data and then I can resize it inside the image with a script? I think it is safer because I can unmount it and shrink it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the UUU, but as I see it's the only tool to burn images without any other option. I'm using a bash script to flash eMMC on my module and create partitions. When you build your image, you'll receive tar.gz file with the root directory. You can easily write in bash script which makes a partition on eMMC, extracts the archive with new files, and then change it.

Comment: That's not possible in my case, I have one idea for now, which is I create the final image with extra partition for data, and then when I boot I extend it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the size of your partition with fdisk before using resize2fs: delete the current partition and create a new one that starts at the same block as the one you deleted.

For example:

```
$ fdisk /dev/mmcblk1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 27.86 GiB, 29896998912 bytes, 58392576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x35a60061

Device         Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1 *     16384  186775  170392 83.2M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2      196608 7071881 6875274  3.3G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 2

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 27.86 GiB, 29896998912 bytes, 58392576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x35a60061

Device         Boot Start    End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1 *    16384 186775  170392 83.2M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 2
First sector (2048-58392575, default 2048): 196608
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (196608-58392575, default 58392575): 

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux' and of size 27.8 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a ext4 signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 27.86 GiB, 29896998912 bytes, 58392576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x35a60061

Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1 *     16384   186775   170392 83.2M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2      196608 58392575 58195968 27.8G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

After that you need to reboot and run resize2fs.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed, it worked :))